# Thread that implements a wait method in OSGi without stopping other bundles

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi, osgi-bundle

I'm having a problem trying to integrate an OSGi bundle that implements a **countdown** in order to send a message in an specific time lapse. This is made by a runnable class, or thread.

The idea is the next; I've got bundle **`Sender`**, bundle **`Receiver`** and bundle **`Countdown`**.

The Sender bundle sends a message after a time lapse, f.e: 5 seconds.

> **Sender** ->Create message
>
> **Countdown** -> Count to 5 s.
>
> **Receiver** ->Receive the message after 5 s.

This is just a "metaphore" of my application, but well, I believe you got the idea.

The problem I'm experiencing is the next one: when the bundle **`Countdown`** is running its 5 seconds countdown, the bundle **`Sender`** stops working (it's OKAY, no problem here), but the bundle **`Receiver`** also stops working. My idea was to implement the countdown in a separate bundle just to avoid other bundles to stop working, but I guess I was wrong.

So, my question is... **how could I implement a countdown that doesn't unnecessarily stop all the bundles of the OSGi application?**

Thanks in advance.

---

Some code:

**`Countdown`**

```
public void countDown()
{
   int i = delay;
   while (i>0){
      try {
        i--;
        Thread.sleep(1000);    // 1000ms = 1 s
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //countdown failure? --> nah
      }
    }
}
```

**`Sender`**

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Countdown(5));
t.start();
while (t.isAlive());
System.out.println("Sending the message");
```

Comment: Could we see some code so we can diagnose the problem?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSGi bundles are neither separate processes, nor separate threads. A bundle doesn't "run"—its code finds itself on the execution path of zero or more threads at any point.

Therefore your question is not at all about OSGi, but about general multithreading in Java. If you want to block a thread while it waits for an answer, and want some other code to keep running, then you must see to it that the other code has its own thread to run in.

Comment: That's why I added the multithreading tag : ). The title may confuse thou, but since I'm working in OSGi I thought it could be helpful for those who experience the same problem. If I understood correctly, if other bundles are not running their own thread, the wait method on some other bundle will always make them stop?

Comment: I think that, as soon as you drop the "running bundles" paradigm and start thinking in terms of running *threads*, you will realize you can answer the question yourself.

Comment: I got a suggestion for this. I just have a thread, so instead making a bundle wait for the thread to finish, I will "fire a trigger" from the thread itself when the countdown gets to 0.

Comment: Well, as I wrote on my question, the bundle executes this: while (t.isAlive()); I know it's not a wait() method, but practically it's making the same thing for this particular example. That while was stopping the entire application, so instead of "waiting" for it to finish, I'll let it run and when it finishes the countdown, I'll make him call the next operation, which is send the message. Hope it is the right approach for my particular problem.